# jQuery duplicate only works on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have found this code on the web and looking to retrofit it for my needs. In the original fiddle it used jQuery 1.7 but I am using 1.10 which they deprecated the `live()` feature I switch the values to `on()` but now it will only work one time (I can duplicate a lot but I can not remove or duplicate after) I included the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/528/). Another thing I have tried doing with the old code but could not get it to work was removing the need to click the duplicate button and instead have it inside of a `for` loop that gets it duplicate value from a variable. I was not getting errors which makes it hard to troubleshoot.

```
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
var locations = 3;
    for(var i = 0; i < locations; i++){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
            .appendTo("body")
            .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
            .find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                }
        });
        cloneIndex++;
    };
```

Comment: Use `.clone(true)` to keep events and data.

Comment: and watch you have unique ids too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a cloned element, you've introduced a *new* DOM element into the document, thus you'd have to make your `.click()` hander to listen to the `$(document`) or `$('body')` to delegate *to* it. Thus if you rewrote your `.click()` handlers like below:

```
$("button.clone").on("click", function(){
    //.clone() etc
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(){
    //.clone() etc
});
```

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/XcbsP/

In the second example, I swapped the HTML ID's in favour of numbered Indexes jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)/[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to help keep track of the index. So in the future if you need to re-select an element, you can:

```
   $(".clonedInput[data-index='2']");
```

Also when creating many new clones your clicked object, pre-increment the counter as you create it:

```
/**
 *  Where $(this).val() is the <option value="2">
**/
for( var x = 0; x < $(this).val(); x++ )
    $('body').append( $(this).parents('.clonedInput')
                             .clone( true )
                             .attr('data-index', ++cloneIndex ));
```

Which makes a cleaner HTML and less dependency on `id=""`s, especially as you're using many of something, which `.classes` are intended for.

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/n6a7e/

Comment: What if I wanted to remove the button and have it clone itself based on a variable value?

Comment: For e.g, make a clone with an index of 2 if there isn't one or? Apologies for clarification

Comment: it's ok basically if a user selects 4 from a drop down menu it will make 4 clones of the div with unique id's basically like clicking the clone button 4 times

Comment: Ah, I see =) Apologies, I had slightly missed the fact the fiddle was slightly different! Thing is, personally I think using `id="some3`" .. `id="some4"` is quite anti-jQuery; I'll update the answer why/how with a demo.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Hopefully a bit like this? http://jsfiddle.net/32kZL/ (I've put number of times in the select boxes)